# Please explain this behaviour (is LINQ cached)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, linq-to-sql, mvc-mini-profiler

I recently added the wonderful [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) package to my project and it helped me a lot to improve page render speed.

Now I notice the following. Every first request to a page takes a significant longer time in SQL than subsequent visits.

Here's an example:

*First visit:*

[image: First visit]

*Second and later visits:*

[image: Second visit]

Is this caused by some sort of caching in LINQ or on SQL Server? I'm using .NET 4 and LINQ-to-SQL with default settings in my dbml file.

Comment: First load of an individual page, or first load of any page after you startup the site?  Initial load times can vary greatly when an application is not warmed up - and cold start profiling should be handled separately from warmed up profiling.  Notice that the time difference is much larger than just the difference in SQL time, which is about 300 ms, compared to a total difference of 1.2 seconds.

Comment: SQL Server has a compiled query cache too.

Comment: First load of any profiled page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of things that can affect the performance of a first hit.  The jitter might have to do some work, and various levels of caching might come into play.

That said, SQL Server has very advanced caching features.  It's not at all unusual for repeat queries against the server to be much faster than the initial query.